# Using 5 threads to run postman folders

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

Is there a way to execute postman folders in parallel in a testng way ?

I have 5 collections, each one contains hundred of tests that are not dependent and use it's own data, so they can be parallalized.

Setting 5 threads can reduce execution time by almost five.

I've seen this [Run Postman (or Newman) collection runner iterations in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998227/run-postman-or-newman-collection-runner-iterations-in-parallel) but it doesn't suite me because it doesn't dynamically know how much folder are in each collection

Is there a way to do so with newman ? Or even with external tools ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use newman and [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

The command would look like: `parallel --jobs 5 < newman_commands.txt`

Where `newman_commands.txt` would contain the newman commands to run each folder.